# macports uninstall problem

Tags: haskell, macports

I originally installed haskell 6.10.4 using macports, but due to some bugs in it, I tried uninstalling it and installing the newer version 6.12.3 directly from the haskell site.

The installer worked fine, but when I start up ghci, it defaults to the macports version 6.10.4 that apparently wasn't uninstalled.

I attempted to use:

```
sudo ports uninstall haskell
```

to get rid of the macports version, apparently unsucessfully.  How do I get macports to totally wipe the version that it put on my drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have installed items that depend on `haskell` then you need to uninstall those first or you can try using the `--follow-dependents` flag:

`sudo port uninstall --follow-dependents haskell`

Alternatively you can use the `--force` switch which will nuke only `haskell` no matter what, but then you may have other items broken which depend on it.

YEa another thing you could do is just make sure the path to the version of haskell you manually installed is before the path to macports on your `$PATH`.

Comment: tried this and I get Error: uninstall does not accept --force